# "View" option to display Local Notification Actions not showing on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am developing an app that requires the use of local notifications that can be triggered in the background. These notifications need to have actions to give the user options. Triggering the notification and adding actions is not the problem; I can't seem to get the actions to display when the notification is triggered while on the lock screen - the "View" button when you swipe left on the notification only gives a cancel option, rather than a view and a cancel option.

I can get the actions to show if I keep the simulator unlocked, and it works fine in the foreground or background. Any help would be appreciated, and I'd be happy to provide code as well.

**My simulator:**

[image]

**What I should see:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If an action is not marked [`.authenticationRequired`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationactionoptions/1648196-authenticationrequired), then it won't appear on the lock screen. If it did, the user could perform the action from the lock screen without unlocking the device, which would be a security hole.

Comment: From your link: "When the user selects an action with this option, the system prompts the user to unlock the device". This would suggest that the action is already visible and selectable from the lock screen, wouldn't it?